# YouTube API not loading consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

For the college I work for I am trying to get a youtube video to auto play in the banner of the webpage. The API is not loading every time properly. I am not sure what I could do to try to fix this.

I have tried:

- Moving the adding of the youtube API script to only when the DOM is ready.
- Placing the code on the top and bottom of the page.
- Checking to see if the player object was created properly and if not try to recreate it which I learned breaks the API.

If I strip the page of everything and just have the banner the video loads more often but still not 100% of the time.

Here I provided the script on the page that is loading the video via the YouTube API.

Update:
From what I can tell by logging to the console the player object is not being fully initialized. 
When it is not created correctly this is what the object print out looks like:

```
Y {b: null, a: null, h: null, closure_uid_165988549: 1, g: 1, …}
```

And here it is when is done correctly:

```
Y {b: Wa, a: iframe#ytplayer, h: div#ytplayer, closure_uid_16195269: 1, g: 1, …}
```

I was wrong about it not finding the videoId. The video is set every time before the function is called so it should not be an issue.

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>

  <script>
    defer(function() {if(window.mobile === true) { $('#ytplayer').remove(); }});
     var ready;
    // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
    // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    // var videoId = 'ZCESafUzSRo';
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      checkFunction();
    }

    function checkFunction() {
      console.log("checkFunction called");
      setYTready(ready);
    }
    function setYTready(ready) {
      console.log("setYT ready called");
      ready = true;
      mtuPlayerCreate(player);
    }

    function mtuPlayerCreate(player) {
      console.log("mtu create called");



      if((player == undefined) && ( document.getElementById("play-yt") != null)) {
    console.log("Creating player");
      player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        height: '52.65%',
        width: '100%',
        playerVars: {
          'controls': 0,
          'showinfo': 0,
          'rel': 0,
          'iv_load_policy': 3
        },
        videoId: videoId,
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          // Removing the following if loop shouldn't be enabled
          onStateChange: 
          function(e){
            if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
              player.playVideo(); 
            }
          }
        }
      });

    }
    console.log("player redo below");
    console.log(player);
      if(player.A == false) {
      //setTimeout(function() {location.reload();}, 2000); 
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }


    function onPlayerReady(event) { /* configuring default playing and mute settings */
      console.log("on ready has been called")
      var autoPlay = 1;
      var autoMute = 1;
      if(autoPlay === 1) { event.target.playVideo(); }
      if(document.getElementById('play-yt') && autoPlay === 1) { document.getElementById('play-yt').className = 'pause'; }else if(document.getElementById('play-yt')) { document.getElementById('play-yt').className = 'play'; }
      if(autoMute === 1) { event.target.mute(); }
      if(document.getElementById('mute-yt') && autoMute === 1) { document.getElementById('mute-yt').className = 'mute'; }else if(document.getElementById('mute-yt')) { document.getElementById('mute-yt').className = 'loud'; }
      if(document.getElementById('yt-yt')) { document.getElementById('yt-yt').className = ''; }
    }

    window.onload = function() { /* this handles what happens when the player and its buttons are clicked on */

            document.getElementsByClassName('media-black')[0].onclick=function(e) { 
        if(e.target.id !== 'yt-yt' && e.target.id !== 'mute-yt') {
          if(player.getPlayerState() === -1 || player.getPlayerState() === 2  || player.getPlayerState() === 5) {  
            player.playVideo(); 
            if(document.getElementById('play-yt')) { document.getElementById('play-yt').className = 'pause'; }
            if (window._gaq) _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Wide Video', 'Played', window.location.href]);
          }else{
            player.pauseVideo(); 
            if(document.getElementById('play-yt')) { document.getElementById('play-yt').className = 'play'; }
            if (window._gaq) _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Wide Video', 'Paused', window.location.href]);
          }
        }
        else if(e.target.id === 'yt-yt' && e.target.id !== 'mute-yt') {
          window.open('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId, '_blank');
          player.pauseVideo();
          if(document.getElementById('play-yt') && document.getElementById('play-yt').className === 'pause') { document.getElementById('play-yt').className = 'play'; }
          if (window._gaq) _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Wide Video', 'Went to YouTube', window.location.href]);
        }else{
          if(player.isMuted() || player.getVolume() === 0) { player.unMute(); player.setVolume(100); document.getElementById('mute-yt').className = 'loud'; }else{ player.mute(); document.getElementById('mute-yt').className = 'mute'; }
          if (window._gaq) _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Wide Video', 'Sound Adjusted', window.location.href]);
        }
      };



    }

    //
    //This could be improved, test if it's mobile and load if not instead of loading and then removing if mobile
    //
    // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
      console.log("dom ready!");
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  });
  </script> 
</div>
```

What it needs to do is:

1. Load the API
2. Load the player object with the given video ID
3. Add the iframe to the correct spot
4. Autoplay the video.

It needs to do this every time the page loads.

Comment: Can you expand on "The API is not loading every time properly"? What is happening instead? Are there any error's in the dev console / networking tab when it doesn't load?

Comment: What I think happens is the player object is loaded with a null value for the video id. There is no errors thrown. I was able to figure this out by printing out to the dev console the player object. What I think is happening is that it does not find the video id due to a sync problems with the loading of the code to the page. Thus resulting in the iframe created by the youtube API loads with a null video. When testing this it would sometimes load the correct video and sometimes not. This may be an issue with youtube API.

Comment: where are you getting the `videoId` from? are you hard coding it?

Comment: Yes it is hard coded into the code. It is being set in the header of the web page. The pages are generated through OU campus which uses XSLT to generate the html for the pages. The video id is parameter for the page being so that is why it is there. This is the code that sets it. `code:<section id="media" title="Aerial view of the Michigan Tech campus." aria-label="Aerial view of the Michigan Tech campus." style="background-image: url('/about/images/campus-1600feature.jpg')" class="jumbo video"><script type="text/javascript">var videoId = 'kED0mcZuifU';</script><div id="videoWrapper">`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're loading the YouTube iframe player in that way, but, I made this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/zntv1Lsf/) - by modifying your code - and I get the YouTube Player iframe working.

These are the modifications I made - you can find more comments in the modified code:

- I commented the line `mtuPlayerCreate` - are you trying to add another YouTube Iframe?
- Add the `onPlayerStateChange` function for set the functionality for HTML elements - able to control the iframe - *"play/pause, (un)mute the video"*.
- The `controls` value was 0, I set it to `1` for check whether it was properly controlling the YouTube iframe by clicking the HTML elements.

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/zntv1Lsf/) code:

```js
// No need for replace the elemnt - YouTube Iframe Player will load in this object and HTML element:
var player;

// This is your videoId "you had it commented".
// it was the video is not available:
//var videoId = 'ZCESafUzSRo';

// Video: "Microsoft Windows Mixed Reality update | October 2018" - by Microsoft Hololens.
var videoId = '00vnln25HBg';

// Check whether iframe is mute.
var isUnMuted = false;

// Here, the YouTube Player API will build the iframe in the "ytplayer" HTML element
// and in the "player" variable.
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
    height: '52.65%',
    width: '100%',
    playerVars: {
      'controls': 1, 
      'showinfo': 1,
      'rel': 0,
      'iv_load_policy': 3,
      'autoplay': 1,
      'loop': 1,
    },
    videoId: videoId,
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });

  // After loading the iframe, set the "playVideo" onclick event on "playButton" anchor element.
  document.getElementById('play-yt').onclick = function() {
    player.playVideo();
  };

  // Thanks to this answer, here you can check the status of "mute" - I culdn't make it work, in the "onPlayerStateChange" function though.
  // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36436765/4092887
  document.getElementById('mute-yt').innerHTML = 'MUTE';
  document.getElementById('mute-yt').onclick = function() {
    player.mute();
  };

  document.getElementById('yt-yt').innerHTML = 'UNMUTE';
  document.getElementById('yt-yt').onclick = function() {
    player.unMute();
  };

}

function checkFunction() {
  console.log("checkFunction called");
  setYTready(ready);
}

function setYTready(ready) {
  console.log("setYT ready called");
  // Not sure what you're doing here = do you want load another youtube iframe?
  //mtuPlayerCreate(player);
}

function mtuPlayerCreate(player) {
  console.log("mtu create called");



  if ((player == undefined) && (document.getElementById("play-yt") != null)) {


  }
  console.log("player redo below");
  console.log(player);
  if (player.A == false) {
    //setTimeout(function() {location.reload();}, 2000); 
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

/* configuring default playing and mute settings */
/* You only need set here the following line: */
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

/* this handles what happens when the player and its buttons are clicked on */
/* You can do it in this way instead: */
function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
  // Removing the following if loop shouldn't be enabled.
  // This is for emulate "loop" functionality.
  if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    player.playVideo();
  }

  // If the video is PLAYING, set the onclick element for pause the video.
  // Once the "playButton" is clicked, the video will be paused.
  if (e.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    document.getElementById('play-yt').innerHTML = 'PAUSE';
    document.getElementById('play-yt').onclick = function() {
      player.pauseVideo();
    };
  }

  // If the video is PAUSED, set the onclick element for pause the video.
  // Once the "playButton" is clicked, the video will resume the video = continue playing the video.
  if (e.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
    document.getElementById('play-yt').innerHTML = 'PLAY';
    document.getElementById('play-yt').onclick = function() {
      player.playVideo();
    };
  }

}

//
//This could be improved, test if it's mobile and load if not instead of loading and then removing if mobile
//
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("dom ready!");
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ytplayer"></div>

<p>
  <div>
    <span>Control your Youtube Iframe Player:</span>
  </div>

  <div id="play-yt">PLAY</div>
  <div id="mute-yt">MUTE</div>
  <div id="yt-yt">UNMUTE</div>
</p>
```